# What is community awarded bounty?

Tags: support, bounty-awards

See this answer:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12216/which-features-from-other-ides-editors-you-wish-you-have-in-visual-studio/22729#22729

It has got a +25 bounty from the community, which looks like this:

[image: This answer has been awarded bounty worth 25 reputation by Community]

It says in the tooltip on the red box with +25:

> This answer has been awarded bounty worth 25 reputation by Community

What is this? How is it awarded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

specifically

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.